# The parameter *pBookmark is invalid for CPage::Load. [SAS Add in for Excel]

Tags: sas, ms-office

Would anyone be able to help me debug the following error as I am unsure what is causing it:

> The parameter *pBookmark is invalid for CPage::Load.

-------------------------- Technical Information Follows --------------------------

### Exception Details:

> Exception type: System.ArgumentException Message: The parameter
>   *pBookmark is invalid for CPage::Load. Target Site: GetRows
>
> Stack Trace: at ADODB.RecordsetClass.GetRows(Int32 Rows, Object Start,
>   Object Fields) at SAS.Servers.Dataset.Read(Int32 startRow) at
>   SAS.OfficeAddin.Rendering.ExcelDataRenderer.RenderSasData(SasDataSource
>   dataSource, Range destination, RenderState state, RenderOptions
>   options, Int32 cachedRowCount) at
>   SAS.OfficeAddin.ExcelAddin.ProcessDataView(JobContext context, Range
>   destination) at SAS.OfficeAddin.ExcelAddin.ProcessDataViews(JobContext
>   context) at SAS.OfficeAddin.OfficeAddinBase.PostProcessJob(JobContext
>   jobContext, Boolean promptOnErrors)

The issue arises when opening a SAS data source.

I'm using SAS Add-In for Microsoft Office version 7.100.0.2122.

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: To check I've got this right: you didn't write CPage::Load, nor are you calling it directly? (i.e. you can't show us that code?) This is an error you're getting from the SAS Add-in when you try to use it? I'd guess we'd need to see how you've configured the SAS Add-in, and maybe someone can spot something wrong with that. Or either way you might do better talking to SAS directly.

Comment: I neither wrote CPage::Load, nor am I calling it directly. It's an error I am getting when I try to pull certain datasets, but it works for others. All the datasets are created using the same process, which leads me to believe my Add-in is configured correctly. I'll try speak directly to SAS and see if they can shed light on the issue.
Thanks for the advice!